# Connecting a PHP Page to a MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For a class that I'm taking, I'm expected to connect my PHP site up to a MySQL server. The problem is, the textbook we're given only specifies how to connect to a localhost, and not to a server.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:http://(domain here); dbname=(My database)";
$username = "(my username)";
$password = "(my password)";


try {
  $conn = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
```

I don't really see any issues with the code as is, and yet a I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Am I doing something wrong or overcomplicating things? I've tried various different usernames, passwords, et cetera. For my domain, I'm currently using the domain of my website, should I use the domain of my PHP configuration instead? (itd1.collegename.edu/phpMyAdmin/ as opposed to itd1.collegename.edu/MyName)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php in case you haven't read the manual.

Comment: You _don't_ want the `http://`. That isn't part of the hostname. Only `(domain here)` is the hostname you should be using for the DSN: `$dsn = "mysql:host=the.server.domain;dbname=yourdatabase";`

Comment: Regarding the 500 - always when developing code, you should have PHP's error display turned on. Although your web server error log probably has logged the details of that error, you can get PHP to display it right on the screen, making it quicker to understand what's gone wrong. Always in development, at the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And this by the way, is the official documentation for PDO MySQL DSN strings: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: Michael, I did fix that, however I still have a 500 error, I tried using the Error reporting script, but regrettably nothing has changed, there is still no context.